# ReactJS images not showing in azure app service, but do show locally

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

First time posting here, so if more information is needed let me know. I have a react app(used create react app) that is just a front end. I pushed it to azure app service and the images won't load, but the console shows no errors as to why. The images load fine on my local machine and again the only error I see is Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. fontawesome-webfont.woff2/:1. I don't think that is related, but I could be wrong.

So far I have tried changing the directory of the images in other folders as suggested from some google searches such as place them in the public folder.I have tried adding different things to the web config such as removing extensions and mimetype tags, and making sure images have required in the the jsx files. Pretty much anything I can find on google.

Below is a snippet of my wepack config and web config. If anything else is needed please let me know.

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
    <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    <remove fileExtension=".json" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**webpack.config snippet**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js','.jsx','.*']
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
 module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            loader:'babel-loader'},
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {},
                },
            ],
        }
    ]
 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you try to open the url directly in the browser and check on the developer tools network section, what do you get?

Comment: On the network tab it appears everything is loading other than I am seeing the same error there as in the console regarding the woff and woff2 font failing. Everything else including my logo image is 200 status. Let me know if I can provide any other information and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is missing a loader for your fonts files on `webpack.config`. You may try to add this rule in the `webpack.config`. Don't forget to install [webpack file-loader lib](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/).

```js
// for fonts
{
  test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/i,
  use: [{
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      fallback: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
      }
    }
  }]
},
// for images
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)(\?.*)?$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 4096,
      fallback: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
      }
    }
  }]
},
```

Comment: aquilesb thank you very much as this fixed the console errors I was seeing. However, the images are still not loading on the server. But again thank you for the help with this it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add a rule for images as well. I have edited my answer and have added a rule for them.

Comment: aquilesb thank you very much for all the help. The images are loading now, but I had to add one thing to the loader. That would be the following loader: "url-loader?name=app/images/[name].[ext]" and that was able to fix the issue. Again thanks for all the help!